# how to sum values between columns in grid view with IFCondition?

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0

i have 3 columns in gridview, Column_A, Column_B and Column_total. then i do simple calculation between Column_A and Column_B and put it in Column_total.. example: when i enter value 1 in row Column_A and 1 in row Column_B, Column_total displays result 2. this simple code works:

```
private void Gdv_CellEndEdit(object sender, GridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (GridViewDataRowInfo Val in Gdv.SelectedRows)
        {
            Val.Cells["Column_Total"].Value =  Convert.ToInt32(Val.Cells["Column_A"].Value) + Convert.ToInt32(Val.Cells["Column_B"].Value);
        }
    }
```

but in Column_total still showing result when I delete value in Column_A..

What I want, Column_total shows result when I enter value in Column_A, then when I delete value in Column_A then Column_total will return empty and won't show any result.. anyone can help?

Comment: If the grids data source is a `DataTable`, have you considered using an [“Expression” Column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datacolumn.expression?view=net-6.0) for Column C? It may simplify things to use a `DataTable` adding column C as an expression column.

Comment: @JohnG actually my gridview data source is taken from mysql database, i just explain in simple. but can it also be done for mysql datasource?

I'm still learning slowly

Comment: Well… if you are getting the data from a DB, then chances are good it is a `DataTable` but this is unknown. If it is, then your code will have to add the “Expression” column C to the table returned from the DB. Then use that `DataTable` as a `DataSource` to the grid.

Comment: @JohnG aah.. your suggestion paved the way, looks like adding an "expression" column can solve it easily..

Comment: @JohnG I've tried and it works as I expected.. thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

Your method is not being recalled to reassign the updated value, I can only guess your .value is a string as you are using convert and didn't specify.

```
private void Gdv_CellEndEdit(object sender, GridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    bool _; /*Throw away value true/false output not needed, 
              prevents compiler warning.*/

    foreach (GridViewDataRowInfo Val in Gdv.SelectedRows)
    {
        _ = int.TryParse(Val.Cells["Column_A"].Value, out a);
        _ = int.TryParse(Val.Cells["Column_B"].Value, out b);

        Val.Cells["Column_Total"].Value = (a != 0 || b != 0) ? (a + b) : "";

        //If a or b is not 0, as int cannot be null; will sum(a+b), else return "" empty.
        //Can change the or || to && if you require both to have values > 0.
    }
}
```

Comment: your guess is right.. i will try your code..

Comment: I used TryParse only because it wont give erros if an invalid char or strings is used it will just out 0 and throw a false into the bool.

Comment: the code you provided got an error after "out" exactly in the "a" part..

Answer (score 0):

finally.. 
agree with @JohnG, to solve my question problem is to use column expression.
this is the last code snippet of my project :

```
  // Create second column.
  DataColumn Col_A = new DataColumn();
  Col_A .DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Decimal");
  Col_A .ColumnName = "Column_A";

  // Create second column.
  DataColumn Col_Total = new DataColumn();
  Col_Total .DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Decimal");
  Col_Total .ColumnName = "Column_total";
  Col_Total .Expression = "Column_A * Column_B";

  // Add columns to DataTable.
  dt.Columns.Add(Col_A);
  dt.Columns.Add(Col_Total);

  DataView view = new DataView(dt);
  dgv.DataSource = view;
```

I added 2 new columns named "Col_A" and "Col_Total" and in the summation column, the column "Column_B" is obtained from the gridview which displays the data source from mysql.

it really works, and I don't know if there's anything better than this?

Thank you for those of you who have answered my previous question.